# Exporting selected records from a shapefile

Tags: shapefile, export

I have a shapefile consisting of insurance data and point features. I select the features I want, and then I try to go to Data - Export, and a new .shp file.

The process seems to run, but the output is an empty attribute table and I can't visualize the point features either.

I don't find any strange letters in my column names.

Anyone got ideas?

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE! Could you please add the software and the version you are using please?

Comment: Assuming ArcGIS, the process you describe should work fine. The only thing that comes to mind is if you have the selected records button toggled in the attribute table but don't have any records selected. You should still see the points, however.

Comment: I second @recurvate posting a screen shot of the attribute table would make it easy to tell if this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

Using QGIS with the wanted features selected you can right click on the layer or go to the file menu and select "Save Selection as..." Choose Shapefile using the same projection as the original file. Done